# Titanium: How to check if Audio Stream Exists before start playing?

Tags: ios, titanium, audio-streaming, audio-player

I'm building a online radio streaming app and so far it stream and play audio on android and ios. But when I started testing my app on ios device (iphone) I found an error.

"File Error - Unable to configure network read stream"

It happens when the network resets and when I resume iphone from the lock mode and try to resume audioPlayer from the pause mode. The audio player plays what left in the buffer and pop above error. Is there a way to check if the audio stream exists?

I also found if I change the pause button operation to "audioPlayer.stop()" and "start()" this error does not occur. Here's my pause\resume button code

```
pauseResumeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

if(Ti.Network.online) {
    if (Ti.App.player.paused) {

    // I need a condition here to check if audio stream exists before start player.

            pauseResumeButton.backgroundImage="/images/pause.png";          
            Ti.App.player.start();      
    }
    else { 
        pauseResumeButton.backgroundImage="/images/play.png";
        Ti.App.player.pause();  
    }
}
else {
   Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        message: 'Network Offline',
        title: 'Error',
        ok:'Ok'
     }).show(); 
}
});
```

Comment: Don't check ahead of time, just handle the error when it occurs.  The only way to check ahead of time is to connect and stream from it anyway.

Comment: how to handle the error when it occurs? Can I stop the error message from displaying?